# Postfix unable to read ssl certs in default location due to SELinux policy on CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, postfix, selinux

I have installed and configured postfix to use ssl certifcates for sending external mail via a relay. This setup has worked on several other Ubuntu/Centos machines. I have my certificates in:

`/etc/ssl/certs/`

and my postfix setup is as usual in:

`/etc/postfix`

the crucial line in main.cf is:

`smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt`

When I start postfix I get an error in the maillog:

> Mar 17 11:55:36 clarity postfix/smtp[14878]: cannot load Certificate Authority data: disabling TLS support
>
> Mar 17 11:55:36 clarity postfix/smtp[14878]: warning: TLS library problem: 14878:error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:bss_file.c:169:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt','r'):
>
> Mar 17 11:55:36 clarity postfix/smtp[14878]: warning: TLS library problem: 14878:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:bss_file.c:174:
>
> Mar 17 11:55:36 clarity postfix/smtp[14878]: warning: TLS library problem: 14878:error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:by_file.c:279:

This led me to the SELinux audit log, where I see:

`type=AVC msg=audit(1489751736.280:1341): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=14878 comm="smtp" name="AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt" dev=dm-0 ino=2228876 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:postfix_smtp_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file`

So I tried to follow instructions [here](http://centosfaq.org/centos/selinux-and-postfix/) to create a new policy allowing the reading of the cert in it's default location. Unfortunately it still didn't work, same error(s). I moved the cert to the postfix config directory `/etc/postfix`, updated main.cf, restarted postfix and now all is good. My question is how should I have created an SELinux policy to allow postfix to read certificates installed outside it's config directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to run `restorecon -Rv /etc/ssl/` on the machine.

It seems that you have moved the file from your home directory without restoring the file context as you can see in the denial

Comment: This didn't actually fix my problem but +1 for putting me on the right track `chcon -u system_u -t bin_t AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt` sorted out the file to mirror other certs in the directory. You were right that the file was originally copied from /home/*  Thanks

Comment: IMHO, the context for that file should be `system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0` not `bin_t`. `bin_t` is for executable files

Comment: Again, thanks. I rushed and checked (`ls -Z`) the wrong (type of) file. Changing to t_cert also works and is, as you say, more appropriate.